# Openstack console log is empty on nodes whose nova-compute is running on container

Tags: containers, openstack, libvirt, openstack-nova, openstack-horizon

After Openstack migration to the container environment, I cannot get console logs.

- When I run `openstack console log show SERVER_NAME`, it returns nothing.
- When I visit console tab in the instance detail of Horizon UI, it returns nothing.

I checked the instance log file in the nova-compute container and realized that the console.log file is existing.

Containerization of openstack services can be the problem?

Comment: How did you migrate, and how are the nova-compute services containerized? Which OpenStack version is this? Do all instances have the problem, or only instances that existed before migration? Have you checked Nova logs - probably Nova-API and Nova-Compute?

Comment: > How are the nova-compute services containerized?
Using openstack-helm, I deployed openstack services on k8s.

> Which openstack version is this?
I am running train, ussuri and victoria. All of them have the same problem.

> Do all instances have the problem?
Yes.

>Have you checked nova logs?
Yes, nothing special.

Comment: Debug logging in `nova-compute` and `nova-api`? You might be able to correlate `nova-compute` messages with the API request by its request ID. What you describe looks like a bug to me, anyway, at least a bug in the deployment method that you used.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason and it seems valuable to share the solution.

## Reason

When the VM is created by libvirt/qemu, a pty device is created under /dev/pts.
When get console log, Nova checks if the device exists in that path.
But now Nova compute is containerized and /dev/pts is not mounted on it.

## Solution

Mount /dev/pts to the container using `volumeMount` in the container manifest.